# ABP Framework Upload File with Dynamic Form with MVC / Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload, abp

Is there any way to add in a model the option to upload a file using the dynamic form.

I am looking at this example, but it is not a dynamic form.

https://community.abp.io/posts/file-uploaddownload-with-blob-storage-system-in-asp.net-core-abp-framework-d01cbe12

Thank you very much.

Other Links:

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Tag-Helpers/Dynamic-Forms

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do everything with dynamic form. In this case, you should convert your form to a static one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the answer of @malikmasis. I come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do it through a dynamic form.